# eager load non direct relation laravel

Tags: laravel, eager-loading

Assume that we have user belongs to many courses. course belongs to one category. user will be assigned to few courses in one category, hence he will have one category indirectly.
So we can code like
`$user ->find(1)->with('courses')`
`$user->category= $user->courses->first()->category`

to have user with courses and category

Is it possible with eager loading to have some thing like
`$user->find(1)->with('category', 'courses')` ?

Also is it possible to  replace the query sent to the closure used with 'with' clause. ?

Answer (score 1):

`find` will return a single model so in this context, both eager loading and lazy loading are equivalent for direct relationships. For nested relationships you still have benefit from eager loading since only a single query will be done to load the categories for each loaded course.

You can get nested relationships as below:

```
$user = User::with([ 'courses', 'courses.category' ])->find(1);
// These will be pre-loaded
// $user->courses
// $user->courses[0]->category
```

Comment: sure this is the direct case ,however this does address the question.

Comment: @AhmedBahtity the way the constraints are set there's no way to specify that a user will have a single category of courses since each course can belong to a different category and there's no relational constraint that can be made to prevent this.

Comment: This exactly the concern of the question. Does the framework allow it ?
underneath the framework split the queries to two. so like that `select from users ... ` and then `select from categories where id in [id of the selected users]`. the problem is that there is no way to control how the id parts goes in the query. you can just add over them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When you do `User::with('categories')->where(condition)` this will do a query like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE (condition)` and then will do `select from categories where id in (ids retrieved from previous query)` do you need to remove ids from there? I think it would be useful if you shared your data structure and constraints

Comment: I need to receive those IDS and manipulate them my self